# How to apply CT to an improper integral?

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

For this question, I'm not sure if I'm doing it right, can anyone please help me out?

Determine whether the integral is convergent or divergent.

$\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x+3ln(x)}$

$\frac{1}{x+3ln(x)} \ge \frac{1}{x}$

$\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x+3ln(x)} \ge \int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x} $

$\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x} = \lim_{A\to \infty} ln(x)$ at $\infty$ and one, which means it equals inifinity when you evaluate it, making $\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x} $ diverge and thus, that makes $\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x+3ln(x)}$ diverge.

Comment: Your first inequality is backwards.  When you divide by something bigger, you get something smaller, right?

Comment: Oh true, yes, but since the integral of one over x diverges, the whole thing diverges right?

Comment: Just use $\ln x < x$ to get $1/(x +3\ln x ) > 1/(4x)$ and proceed as you did withCT

Comment: note that $\frac{1}{x+3ln(x)} \le \frac{1}{x}$

Comment: Where did the 1 over 4x come from?

Comment: And why are we allowed to do that?

Comment: $ x + 3 \ln x < x + 3x = 4x$

Comment: Allowed to do what? You integrand is bigger than $1/(4x)$ and the integral of that diverges

Comment: Like do $ln(x)<x$ and then what you just commented

Comment: @dg123 When $x\ge1,$ we know that $x>\ln x.$

Comment: Shouldn't it be $x\ge lnx$?

Comment: Since $\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{x+3\log x} = \frac{3\log x}{x(x+3\log x)} \leq 3\frac{\log x}{x^2}$ and $\int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{\log x}{x^2}\,dx=1$, you have $$ \int_{1}^{M}\frac{dx}{x+3\log x}\,dx \geq \log(M)-3.$$

Comment: @RRL isn't 1 over four x supposed to be greater than 1 over x plus 3lnx?

Comment: @dg123 Please remember that you can choose an aswer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Note that

$$ \frac{1}{x+3\ln(x)}\sim \frac1x$$

indeed for $x\to \infty$

$$\frac{\frac{1}{x+3\ln(x)}}{\frac1x}\to 1$$

then use [limit comparison test](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/SeriesCompTest.aspx) with $\sum \frac1x$.

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{1}{x + 3\ln(x)} >\frac{1}{x + 3(x-1)} =\frac{1}{4x-3}>\frac{1}{4x}$ for $x > 1$. So the integral diverges.

Comment: Could I do it the other way and say since it doesn't converge, it must mean it diverges?

Comment: Yes, if it does not converge it automatically diverges. But I do not see how this would be different.

Comment: Isn't x supposed to be greater than lnx?

Answer (score 0):

Your comparison test is incorrect. This is because:

$$\frac{1}{x+3\ln(x)} \leq \frac{1}{x} \quad x \in [1, \infty)$$

Since $\ln x \geq 0 \,\forall x \in [1, \infty)$, then the denominator must be greater than or equal to $1\over x$'s denominator. Larger denominators mean smaller quantities overall, so you cannot draw any conclusion.

Instead apply some other test, such as the limit comparison test for integrals, for convergence.